# how to reverse the list in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my filtering i want to change the order to display the list like last in first out(reverseorder).
my code is in repository.cs

orderby candidate.Position ascending
select candidate);

how to change instead of orderby to reverse order.

Comment: Are you sure you mean mvc (Model-View-Controller)?

Comment: Is this what you need: `ascending` => `desending`?

Comment: Are you one of the people who refers to IE as "the internet" ? If not, then why are you referring to ASP.NET MVC framework as simply MVC (which is a language independent design pattern) ?

Comment: I found the solution.No need to change orderby .i have to change instead of position to datetime.Because the entries are based on time only.so that i ordered the date wise. thanks for response.

Comment: @tereško Probably because we don't all want to refer to the "ASP .NET MVC framework" all the time. Takes a bit to type all that. Just "MVC" is fine with me - we all know what it means (those of us that use it, anyway).

Comment: @vapcguy the problems begin when people apply the same logic to choosing post tags =P

Answer (score 1):

It will go something like this:

```
candidates = candidates.OrderBy(c => c.Position).ToList()
```

For decending order:

```
candidates = candidates.OrderByDescending(c => c.Position).ToList()
```

Comment: Even if it might not help the OP, it helped me!  Forgot about `OrderByDescending`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do it in runtime.

Try **[Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)** library.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when I was trying to reverse the order in which the items in my database or model are displayed on my web page. (I wanted to get the most recent first.)

```
@for (int i = Model.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
      //input your div with the relevant model fields
}
```